# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ' ' (T_STRING)

Tags: php, html, magento, parsing

I get this error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '   ' (T_STRING) in >/home/bijouven/public_html/app/design/frontend/default/magikjewellery/template/checkout/success.phtml >on line 30

This is line 30 of success.phtml :

> $orderObj = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($this->getOrderId());

This is the entire code :

```
<?php
/**
 * Theme: Magik Jewellery
 * Author: MagentoMagik.com
 * Version: 1.5
 * URL: http://www.magentomagik.com/magento-themes/free-magento-themes/magik-jewellery-magento-theme/
 * Source: http://www.magentomagik.com/ piono checkout success dineromail
 **/ 
?>
<div style="text-align:center;">
<div class="page-head">
    <h2><?php echo $this->__('') ?></h2>
</div>
<?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml() ?>

<div style="position: absolute; z-index: 0;">
    <img src="<?php echo($this->getSkinUrl('images/success.png')) ?>" alt="" usemap="#Map" style="border:5px solid #333; margin-top:4px;">
</div>

<div style="position: relative; z-index: 1;">
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>

<?php
     //loading the order object 
    $orderObj = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($this->getOrderId());
    //get all the items included on the order. 
    /* $orderItems = $orderObj->getAllItems();

    //do a loop to get the sku of each item
foreach($orderItems as $item)
{
  //you can either echo each sku of the order / you can use array variable to pass items sku’s
  echo  $item->getSku();
} */
    $orderSubTotal = $orderObj ->subtotal;
    $orderGrandTotal = $orderObj ->grand_total;
    $orderGrandTotal = number_format($orderGrandTotal, 2, '.', '');
    $email = $orderObj ->customer_email;
    $firstname = $orderObj ->customer_firstname;
    $lastname = $orderObj ->customer_lastname;
    $payment_method = $orderObj->getPayment()->getMethodInstance()->getCode();
    $phone = $orderObj ->getShippingAddress()->getData("telephone");

    switch ($payment_method){
        case cashondelivery:
            $payment_method = "contra";
            break;
        case banktransfer:
            $payment_method = "deposito";
            break;
        case checkmo2:
            $payment_method = "ar_visa;ar_master;ar_argencard;ar_amex;ar_tnaranja;ar_cabal;ar_tshopping;ar_italcred;";
            break;
        case checkmo1:
            $payment_method = "ar_pagofacil;ar_rapipago;ar_cobroexpress;ar_bapropago;";
            break;
        default:
            $payment_method = "other";
    }
    if ($payment_method == "contra")
    {
        ?>
        <strong>
          <?php if ($this->canPrint()) :?>
          <?php echo $this->__('Tu número de pedido es el #: <a href="%s">%s</a>', $this->getViewOrderUrl(), $this->getOrderId()) ?>.
          <?php  else :?>
          <?php echo $this->__('Tu número de pedido es el #: %s', $this->getOrderId()) ?>.
          <?php endif;?><br><br>
        </strong>
        <br/><br><br>
        <strong>
            <?php echo $this->__('En breve recibirás un mail de confirmación con los detalles') ?>
        </strong>
        <br/><br><br><br><br><br>
            <?php if ($this->canPrint()) :?>
            <?php echo $this->__('Click <a href="%s" onclick="this.target=\'_blank\'">here to print</a> a copy of your order confirmation.', $this->getPrintUrl()) ?>
            <?php endif;?>

            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml() ?>
        </div>
        <?php /*?><div class="button-set">
            <button type="button" class="form-button" onclick="window.location='<?php echo $this->getUrl() ?>'"><span><?php echo $this->__('Continue Shopping') ?></span></button>
        </div><?php */?>
        </div><?php 
    }
    if ($payment_method == "deposito")
    {
        ?> 
        <span>Se ha enviado un mail con los detalles del pedido a <?php echo $email?></span>
        <br>
        <br>
        <strong>
            Datos de la cuenta bancaria donde efectuar el depósito/transferencia:
        </strong>
        <span>
            <br>
            BANCO SANTANDER RIO
            <br>
            CUENTA CORRIENTE NUMERO: 367303/6
            <br>
            SUCURSAL FLORESTA 020
            <br>
            TITULAR: Martin Kruszyn
            <br>
            CUIT: 20345839489
            <br>
            CBU: 0720020588000036730368
            Una vez realizado el depósito/transferencia por favor enviar comprobante a:<br>
            info@bijouventas.com.ar.
            <br>
            Una vez acreditado el pago, le enviaremos su pedido en un plazo de 48-72 horas hábiles.
        </span>
        <br/>
            <?php if ($this->canPrint()) :?>
            <?php echo $this->__('Click <a href="%s" onclick="this.target=\'_blank\'">here to print</a> a copy of your order confirmation.', $this->getPrintUrl()) ?>
            <?php endif;?>

            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml() ?>
        </p>
        </div>
        <?php /*?><div class="button-set">
            <button type="button" class="form-button" onclick="window.location='<?php echo $this->getUrl() ?>'"><span><?php echo $this->__('Continue Shopping') ?></span></button>
        </div><?php */?>
        </div>
        <?php
    }
    if ($payment_method != "other" && $payment_method != "deposito" && $payment_method != "contra")
    { ?>
        <strong>
          <?php if ($this->canPrint()) :?>
          <?php echo $this->__('Tu número de pedido es el #: <a href="%s">%s</a>', $this->getViewOrderUrl(), $this->getOrderId()) ?>.
          <?php  else :?>
          <?php echo $this->__('Tu número de pedido es el #: %s', $this->getOrderId()) ?>.
          <?php endif;?><br><br>
        </strong>
        <td width="100%" align="center">
            <form action="https://checkout.dineromail.com/CheckOut" target="_self" method="post" id="dineromail">
                 <input type="hidden" name="merchant" value="bijouventaspagina@gmail.com">

                 <input type="hidden" name="country_id" value="1"> 
                 <input type="hidden" name="language" value="es">
                 <input type="hidden" name="currency" value="ars">
                 <input type="hidden" name="change_quantity" value="0"> 
                 <input type="hidden" name="display_shipping" value="0"> 
                 <input type="hidden" name="payment_method_available" value="<?php echo $payment_method?>"> 
                 <input type="hidden" name="transaction_id" value="<?php echo $this->getOrderId() ?>"> 
                 <input type="hidden" name="display_additional_charge" value="0">

                 <input type="hidden" name="seller_name" value="Bijou Ventas"> 

                 <input type="hidden" name="buyer_name" value="<?php echo $firstname ?>"> 
                 <input type="hidden" name="buyer_lastname" value="<?php echo $lastname ?>"> 
                 <input type="hidden" name="buyer_phone" value="<?php echo $phone ?>"> 
                 <input type="hidden" name="buyer_email" value="<?php echo $email ?>"> 

                 <input type="hidden" name="header_image" value="http://bijouventas.com.ar/skin/frontend/default/magikjewellery/images/logo.png">
                 <?php /*<input type="hidden" name="pending_url" value="http://casamundial.com.ar/index.php?option=com_virtuemart&amp;page=checkout.resultdm&amp;er=1&amp;order_id=2558"> 
                 <input type="hidden" name="error_url" value="http://casamundial.com.ar/index.php?option=com_virtuemart&amp;page=checkout.resultdm&amp;er=2&amp;order_id=2558"> 
                 */ ?>
                 <input type="hidden" name="ok_url" value="http://bijouventas.com.ar/index.php/"> 

                <input type="hidden" name="item_name_1" value="A pagar">
                <input type="hidden" name="item_quantity_1" value="1"> 
                <input type="hidden" name="item_ammount_1" value="<?php echo $orderGrandTotal ?>"> 
                <input type="hidden" name="item_currency_1" value="ars"> 

                <br><b>PARA TERMINAR SU COMPRA, DEBE EFECTUAR EL PAGO.</b>
                <br><b>EN CASO DE NO SER REDIRECCIONADO AL SITIO DE DINERO MAIL, HAGA CLICK EN EL BOTON DE ABAJO</b><br><br>
                <input type="image" src="https://argentina.dineromail.com/imagenes/botones/pagar-medios_c.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="Pagar con Dineromail">
                <br>Usted sera redirigido a nuestra plataforma de pago online automaticamente <br><br>


<!-- Google Code for Compra Carrito Conversion Page -->
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
var google_conversion_id = 975718772;
var google_conversion_language = "en";
var google_conversion_format = "2";
var google_conversion_color = "ffffff";
var google_conversion_label = "5-yCCOSYgAgQ9JKh0QM";
var google_conversion_value = 1.00;
var google_conversion_currency = "ARS";
var google_remarketing_only = false;
/* ]]> */
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js">
</script>
<noscript>
<div style="display:inline;">
<img height="1" width="1" style="border-style:none;" alt="" src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion/975718772/?value=1.00&amp;currency_code=ARS&amp;label=5-yCCOSYgAgQ9JKh0QM&amp;guid=ON&amp;script=0"/>
</div>
</noscript>
                <script>setTimeout('document.getElementById("dineromail").submit();',1500);</script> 
            </form>    
        </td>
    <?php 
    } ?>


<!-- Facebook Conversion Code for Pixel Comprar -->
<script>(function() {
  var _fbq = window._fbq || (window._fbq = []);
  if (!_fbq.loaded) {
    var fbds = document.createElement('script');
    fbds.async = true;
    fbds.src = '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbds.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(fbds, s);
    _fbq.loaded = true;
  }
})();
window._fbq = window._fbq || [];
window._fbq.push(['track', '6016863737486', {'value':'0.00','currency':'ARS'}]);
</script>
<noscript><img height="1" width="1" alt="" style="display:none" src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?ev=6016863737486&amp;cd[value]=0.00&amp;cd[currency]=ARS&amp;noscript=1" /></noscript>
```

Added ";" and erradicates the "(" & ")" from echo. Still getting same error
**New code between lines 1-30:**

```
<?php
/**
 * Theme: Magik Jewellery
 * Author: MagentoMagik.com
 * Version: 1.5
 * URL: http://www.magentomagik.com/magento-themes/free-magento-themes/magik-jewellery-magento-theme/
 * Source: http://www.magentomagik.com/ piono checkout success dineromail
 **/ 
?>
<div style="text-align:center;">
<div class="page-head">
    <h2><?php echo $this->__(''); ?></h2>
</div>
<?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml(); ?>

<div style="position: absolute; z-index: 0;">
    <img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/success.png'); ?>" alt="" usemap="#Map" style="border:5px solid #333; margin-top:4px;">
</div>

<div style="position: relative; z-index: 1;">
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>

<?php
     //loading the order object 
    $orderObj = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($this->getOrderId());
```

Comment: *Hm...*, might be the `/` in `sales/order` causing that.

Comment: You should **really** be using semi-colons to close **ALL** of you PHP statements such as `<?php echo $this->__('') ?>` into `<?php echo $this->__(''); ?>`. I see three violations between lines 1-29 so fix those and see if you are still having an issue.

Comment: (Unrelated (probably): `echo` is not a function: `echo($this->getSkinUrl(.....`)

Comment: @Rudie `echo` is not a function, thank goodness we aren't blind to ternary operators. `echo(9===9);` displays a literal 1

Comment: @Rudie yes, you are correct with short-tags but these are full tags and OP's current code should be producing parse errors.

Comment: The problem seems to lie between lines 1 and 30. Whatever you have happening with those functions, is most likely the reason why. Unable to reproduce.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Done, i edit and add the code to the post.

Same error

Comment: @Rudie 
I fix echo. (Eliminate "()").

Same error

Comment: @Fred-ii- This error is new, sometime ago works perfectly... So i dont know whats happening, maybe the host change the php version or something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's probably a non-space between `<?php` and the first `$`. Remove all of it, including the comment, using BACKSPACE, and then recreate them with ENTER. There are a lot of sneaky characters that look like white space, but actually aren't.

`unexpected ' ' (T_STRING)` looks like a non-white-space character.

Comment: Line 30 contains `('sales/order')` which has 2x quotes, so that's one thing I'm suspecting; something's not being populated or something wrong with the model. I tested OP's code as much as I could and was unable to reproduce.

Comment: @Rudie 
new error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$orderObj' (T_VARIABLE) in /home/bijouven/public_html/app/design/frontend/default/magikjewellery/template/checkout/success.phtml on line 30

Comment: Did you manually remove ALL the white space? Remove the `<?php` and `$` too and replace them manually. There must be a weird character in there somewhere.

Comment: @Rudie You were right. There was a problem with the .phtml itself, I suppose with non characters in all the document, i rewrite again all exactly. Working!